# How to delete additional line from a DXF file

Tags: graphics

Is there anything I need to add to my code so that the generated DXF file does not contain a diagonal line in the generated profile?

```
g=Graphics[{White,EdgeForm[Thickness[0.01]],Rectangle[{0,0},{250,180}]}]
Export["C:\\Users\\Leandro\\Desktop\\Plaquinha.dxf",g]
```

When I open the DXF file in a CAD application, an additional diagonal line appears that I don't want to exist.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Quick guess: rectangles are no primitives in DXF. Second guess: rectangles *are* primitives in DXF but *Mathematica's* export filter doesn't know it.

In both cases, *Mathematica* does what it also has to do when sending `Polygon` objects to the GPU: It splitts each polygon into a set of triangles.

Workaround: If you do not need any filling, but only the lines around the rectangle, replace

```
Rectangle[{0, 0}, {250, 180}]
```

by

```
RegionBoundary[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {250, 180}]]
```

Comment: Graphics3D contains no data that can be exported to the DXF format.

Comment: @LCarvalho It does, but you turned it `White`t! ;)  The `RegionBoundary` of a `Reactangle` is a `Line` object, so the color directives apply to it directly and `EdgeForm` does nothing on it.